# Databricks: looping dataframe and put to variable

Tags: scala, databricks

Suppose I have a dataframe 
Col1 Col2
1    A
2    B

I would like to loop this table in a while loop and in to loop
var variable to col2 value.

while ()
var var1 = (dataframe col2 value )

anyway to do this in scala language ?

Comment: Do you understand that a `DataFrame` is a distributed collection, that is splitted across many machines, and that a **while** is a local instruction, that will be only executed in the Driver node? - and that if you use `collect` to bring all the data to the Driver it may blow up your memory?

Comment: so what's does it mean ? Any other method ?

Comment: the table for looping is small, within 100 rows and 2 to 3 columns only

Comment: If the data is small, why are you using **Spark**? which is a BIG DATA technology, intended for processing billions of records. If it is just for learning, you do not win nothing doing things that wont work on real use cases. I think you may first read about the basis of the Spark execution model.